# Odoo 14 field does not get added to res.company

Tags: python, inheritance, odoo, odoo-14

I simply want to add two new Binary fields to the res.company model

To achieve this, in my module, I have added a "company.py" file in the module/models folder

```py
from odoo import models, fields

class Company(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.company'

    header = fields.Binary(string="Header")
    footer = fields.Binary(string="Footer")
```

and I have added a "company.xml" file in my module/views folder which looks like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="view_company_form_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">res.company.form.view.inherited</field>
            <field name="model">res.company</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_company_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='vat']" position="before">
                <field name="header"/>
                <field name="footer"/>
            </xpath>  
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>

</odoo>
```

in the **manifest**.py file I have added views/company.xml in the data list.
I have imported the company file in the **init**.py file like this:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from . import [other models], company, [other models]
```

unfortunately, when I try to load the module in odoo I get the following error:

```
Field "header" does not exist in model "res.company"

View name: res.company.form.view.inherited
Error context:
 view: ir.ui.view(1772,)
 xmlid: view_company_form_inherited
 view.model: res.company
 view.parent: ir.ui.view(107,)
 file: /PATH/TO/MODULE/views/company.xml
```

To me, this looks like the modified view works fine, but the py file somehow has not added the two fields 'header' and 'footer' to the 'res.company' model.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating `res` tables like `res.company` you need to start your server with the `-u your_module` option to perform a succesful update.